# Undesired clipping when resizing wpf control under certain tresshold

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, clipping

When developing a custom control in WPF I noticed a strange clipping behavior. When I resize the control under a certain minimum boundaries/tress-hold it decides to clip the top 24 pixels of the control for reasons I don't understand.

It would be much appreciated if somebody could explain how i can achieve the desired graphical effect without clipping behavior as illustrated.

[image: Image with no clipping - Expected]
[image: Image with top 24 pixels clipped - Unexpected]

The behavior occurs with the following XAML. Note that the XAML is a stripped down to make the it compliant with standard .net 4.0 controls.

```
        <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="Border" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
                        <Polygon x:Name="Arrow" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,8,3,3" Opacity="0.15" Points="0,10 10,10 10,0" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Arrow" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Border Background="Transparent" Margin="0,24,0,0" >
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                                            <Button Grid.Row="0" Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Row="0" x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" ClipToBounds="False">
                                                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                    <TranslateTransform Y="-24" />
                                                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Rectangle Fill="Yellow" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Column="1" Height="48" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,12" Name="dataGrid1" Width="868" FrozenColumnCount="2"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" 
              AreRowDetailsFrozen="True" CanUserAddRows="False" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle1}"
              ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Layer Name" Width="250" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="" Width="150" IsReadOnly="True" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="*" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>                        
                    <Grid Height="18">
                        <TextBlock Text="100.0f" Margin="0,-10" />    
                    </Grid>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>     
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <StackPanel>

                                        <TextBlock Text="test" />
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>                                
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>                        
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>  
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a few days of fiddling I found the culprit to be GetLayoutClip method. This method returns clipping geometry *only* if the bounds of the control is smaller than the minimum bounds.

Easiest solution to override this behavior was to make a custom control inherit from the said base control. And to construct new clipping geometry with the extra margin taken into account.