# WPF creates undesired margin when ColumnDefinitions' widths are dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, grid-layout

Here's a WPF Window that contains a `UserControl`. The `UserControl` is a simple `Grid` with 2 columns without definite Widths. In the first column, I added a simple `TextBox` set to stretch horizontally. The second column is empty.

As I shrink the window's width, WPF crops my `UserControl` even though there's still a huge blank space available on its right! It looks as it's trying to have my second column the same size as my first column even if it's empty, but oddly, this happens outside of my UserControl (else the blank space would be pink!)...

**MainWindow.XAML**:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Grid_Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Grid_Test"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <local:TestUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
</Window>
```

**UserControl.XAML**:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_Grid_Test.TestUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Background="Pink" Height="100">
    <Grid Margin="0" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="Why is WPF cropping me even though there's a huge blank space to eat into?" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I tried setting all `Margins` and `Paddings` to 0, no change.

When the `UserControl` is set to center horizontally (instead of left), *the behavior is even weirder!* Instead of creating a huge margin on the right, the margin is actually distributed evenly on the left and on the right. I would like the dynamic resize of my `UserControl` to happen only after WPF used up all the available space. Isn't that what any programmer would expect?

*(My real project actually has 3 columns, respectively containing a TextBlock, a TextBox and a Button, but the behavior is the same: the UIElements will be cropped before WPF eats into its own auto-generated margin)*

When I set definite Widths on the columns (that, or "Auto"), WPF will correctly get rid of its blank spaces before cropping my UserControl. But this prevents WPF to shrink the UserControl as the window gets even thinner.

So my first question is, **isn't this a WPF bug?**

My second question, **how to setup the columns so that WPF only starts resizing my UserControl once it's *REALLY* out of space to display it?**

This is .NET 4.0. A similar question exists [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055047/undesired-clipping-when-resizing-wpf-control-under-certain-tresshold) but I don't really understand the solution.

**UPDATE:**
Here's another sample code for the `UserControl`. When setting the Column Widths to "Auto" as suggested, the `UserControl` will stop shrinking its elements as the window is shrinked and will eventually crop the rightmost element once space is really lacking:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPF_Grid_Test.TestUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         Background="Pink" Height="100">

    <Grid Margin="0" ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox Text="Resize us" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBox Text="only when" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="1" />
        <TextBox Text="you're out of space!" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is that the `UserControl` retains its `DesiredSize` as I shrink the window. But *only when the window is out of blank space*, should the `UserControl` receive the "shrinking" treatment.

Try to remove the `Width=Auto` from the ColumnDefinitions, and you should see how the rightmost element is being resized *before* the container lacks space. This is why I think this is indeed a WPF layout bug.

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly specify the width of the columns.

For example, if you want both columns to be always the same size, use `Width="*"`.
If you want both columns to be as wide as necessary, use `Width="Auto"`. This will lead to columns that are of different size.
If you want one column to be as wide as necessary and the other to use the remaining space, use `Width="Auto"` on the first column and `Width="*"` on the second column.

Comment: Setting these gives a fixed width to the UserControl based on its content, which isn't the behavior I'm looking for. I am OK with the UserControl resizing itself and cropping its elements when space is lacking. If you try the above code, you'll notice the UserControl is shrinked even though the Container *does* have the space to show it all.

Comment: I have updated my initial post with your idea, and explained how it doesn't provide the expected behavior.